# Adding rows to dataframe using lapply

Tags: r, pdf

I am trying to extract data from a pdf then  enter it into a row in a dataframe. I have figured out how to extract the data I want, but the last two parts Im not able to figure out yet. I've set up a basic function to try with lapply and it gives me a 1 row, 39 observation dataframe with the information I want as characters properly formatted and

```
filenames <- list.files("C:/Users/.../inputfolder", pattern="*.pdf")

function01 <- function(x) {
df1 <- pdf_text(x) |>
str_squish() |>
mgsub ()|>
etc
}

master_list <- lapply(filenames, function01)

mdf <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, master_list))
```

So right now this works for one pdf and Im not quite sure how to make it apply to all files in the folder properly and add the data to the rows of mdf.

Comment: why don't you use a for loop to go through each file, something like for `( f in filenames){
# run you code. 
}`

Comment: Also if you anticipate a big dataframe rbind is going to be very slow, instead use dplyr::bind_rows

Comment: Note: `dplyr::bind_rows(master_list)` is **much** faster than `do.call(rbind, master_list)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr:map_dfr`.
This function calls the function in a loop, then returns the output as a data.frame, with a row for every iteration:

```
library(purrr)

master_list <- map_dfr(filenames, function01)
```